# specifying CSS class on ime_zone_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, form-helpers

Is there a way to specify CSS class on time_zone select helper. I have the code like -

> f.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applying CSS class on time_zone_select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048367/applying-css-class-on-time-zone-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
time_zone_select(:time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones, {}, {:class => 'css-class-name'})
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-time_zone_select

Comment: thanks that worked like charm and got to learn a new thing about sorting out problem.