# Applying CSS class on time_zone_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

Is it possible to provide a CSS class for the time_zone_select  FormHelper in Rails 3.
I currently have something like

```
f.time_zone_select :time_zone
```

Have tried options like -

> f.time_zone_select :time_zone, nil, :class => 'classname'

But that does not work

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
f.time_zone_select :time_zone, nil, {}, {:class => 'classname'}
```

Answer (score 11):

Just in case anyone is wondering where to add the :default =>

```
f.time_zone_select :time_zone, nil, {:default => default_timezone}, {:class => 'classname'}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin! Super helpful.